# How to measure the area of polygons within a fishnet

Tags: arcgis-10.0, area, dissolve

I am currently trying to measure the area of polygons within each square of a fishnet.  The aim of what I am doing is to work out the proportion of different agri-environment schemes by 1km squares.  I have tried following the instructions in the pdf below but when it comes to the dissolve I get a 'warning empty output'.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image: Using the intersect function creates the layer below and cannot be used to calculate area within squares]

http://www.cabnr.unr.edu/weisberg/downloads/polygons_within_polygons.pdf

Comment: Have you tried just using Union followed by Summary Statistics?

Comment: Thanks, i have just tried that but it gives the sum area of the whole layer rather than by fishnet square.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to wait until i get an Arcinfo license and split it

Comment: I think you may want to dissolve your agri-schemes prior to the intersection/union.  Then you wouldn't have multiple smaller polygons of the same type within each square and you could easily export/summarize area by class for each.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you´re looking for something like this(labels denote area in sqkm):
[image: Intersect]

You can just [intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) the Fishnet with the Polygon Layer.

Comment: Using the intersect function produced the layer i have posted in my question, I can't use this to calculate areas within the fishnet squares...Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The areas of the intersecting polygons should be calculated in the "Shape_Area" field of the Intersect Output already.